# How to load/unload binary blob from PostgreSQL with D?

Tags: postgresql, blob, d

I load image in PostgreSQL with next command:

```
UPDATE "USERS" SET userblob = (pg_read_binary_file('img.png')::bytea) WHERE id>1;
```

The field type is: bytea

Now DB like [this](http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/07/57060da185b19.png).

Then I tried to write binary blob back to file system. And got very big file that include data like: `[56, 57, 53, 48, 52, 101, 52, 55, 48, 100, 48, 97, 49 ...`

What I am doing wrong? My code is next:

```
struct MyData
{
    string  guid;
    string  id;
    string  name;
    byte [] userblob;
    string  fl;
}   
        auto rs = pgstmt.executeQuery(`SELECT guid::text, id, name, userblob, "FL" FROM "USERS" where "FL" = 10;`);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        md.guid = to!string(rs.getString(1));
        md.id = to!string(rs.getString(2));
        md.name = to!string(rs.getString(3));
        md.userblob = rs.getBytes(4);
        md.fl = to!string(rs.getBytes(5));

        std.file.write("output.png", cast(byte[])md.userblob);
        readln;

        mydata ~= md;
    }
```

UPD: I have read docs. PostgreSQL bytea is pain. It's much better to store all text in base64 encoding. 
Working example:
`UPDATE "USERS" SET userblob = encode(pg_read_binary_file('img.png'), 'base64') WHERE id>1;`

Comment: What client driver are you using? The client driver should be taking care of this for you. PgJDBC does, psqlODBC does, libpq does ... are you using a really limited driver of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem in bytea encoding/decoding function.
Fixed in ddbc v0.2.32

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres bytea seems to be the source of the problem here. From what I could read in the Postgres docs, bytea will store non-printable values of the byte stream as the string representation of the octal value of that value.
This will require some processing to get the actual binary stream back...

You can take a look at how [DDBC](https://github.com/buggins/ddbc/blob/master/source/ddbc/drivers/pgsql.d#L92) handles these.

I would suggest you copy/paste the `byte[] byteaToBytes(string s)` function in one of your project file and adapt your code as follows:

```
while (rs.next())
{
    ...
    md.userblob = byteaToBytes(to!string(rs.getString(4)));
    ...
    std.file.write("output.png", cast(byte[])md.userblob);
    readln;

    mydata ~= md;
}
```

Comment: ```
  byte [] userblob;
  ...
  md.userblob = rs.byteaToBytes(4);
  
Error: no property 'byteaToBytes' for type 'ddbc.core.ResultSet'  
```

Comment: Is there any reason why Postgres do not store bytes directly? Why it convert them to inner format?

Comment: it's look like something still wrong. I can't get original image http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/04/07/57063cd3dc645.png

Comment: The byteaToBytes function from DDBC may not support the particular bytea format used in your case or it may simply be buggy, I don't know. A quick look at the DDBC code seems to show it supports another bytea format. You might need to adapt it...

Comment: Anything except the most prehistoric PostgreSQL version sends and receives bytea with a hex representation with `\x` prefix, not as octal escpaes. You can get raw binary on the wire if your client library supports binary mode. Not all do, especially for niche languages. Either way, the PostgreSQL client driver should be taking care of this for you if it's any good at all.

Comment: `bytea` is stored without any modifications on the server (well, actually the data is compressed). Depending on the client and the protocol chosen, the values might be converted to a hex representation when the data is _transmitted_ **to** the client. But that does not affect the storage of the data